# time reduced by 1in .NET when retrieved from C++ class

Tags: c#, c++, time

When trying to retieve an input datetime from C++ structure and use it in C# code, I noticed the hours are reduced by 1 and then converted to GMT+2 time zone in .NET
there are the modules I use to read time from C++: time.inl and wchar.h

When calling standard C++ classes to retrieve the date and consume it in a .NET classe it happens that the hours are reduced by 1.  it looks like C++ STANDARD date and time functions does convert the system date to some format, therefore the date is sent wrongly to .NEt class.  I'm talkig about the standatd time class in C++ and DateTime class in .NET there is no specific code written that's why I'm not providing any code.

I will try to make my question clearer and that is Has anyone come across this problem before. if Yes please share your findings if not then don't
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Nice tip: the more effort you put in writing a readable and formatted question, the more effort we will put in our answers.

Comment: Question is has anyone come across this problem when time is converted from C++ to C#

Comment: @Idriss: We're still missing the code... please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @Idriss Selhoum: Please edit your question to make it more readable, more informative. People here are not paid nor forced to answer your questions: if you are not willing to spend 30 seconds to fix your question, why should we spent 2 minutes to answer it ?

Comment: @ereOn, you have a good point and I agree. This is going meta...but...For my part, I've kinda decided to stop asking people to ask questions.  They can ask reasonable questions or not, and I can choose to answer or not. The "market" decides.  On this question, I was going to just pass on by, but decided to offer a "guess" answer, only because some of the words in the question reminded me of a problem I confronted a while ago, and i had the solution at hand, and maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear from your question exactly what you are asking, but...it may be that you are observing a difference between time handling in Win32 versus .NET, specifically around "Daylight savings" shifts.

The issue is described in some detail [here by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/24/55413.aspx).

Check it, maybe it is what is troubling you.

I came up with this to adjust times when getting them via Win32 and using them in .NET:

```
    // If I read a time from a file with GetLastWriteTime() (etc), I need
    // to adjust it for display in the .NET environment.
    internal static DateTime AdjustTime_Forward(DateTime time)
    {
        if (time.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc) return time;
        DateTime adjusted = time;
        if (DateTime.Now.IsDaylightSavingTime() && !time.IsDaylightSavingTime())
            adjusted = time + new System.TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);

        else if (!DateTime.Now.IsDaylightSavingTime() && time.IsDaylightSavingTime())
            adjusted = time - new System.TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);

        return adjusted;
    }
```

"Forward" in the name of the method refers to Win32 -> .NET, not "forward" in a temporal sense. It presumes the input time parameter was obtained from something like `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc()`.

This code assumes a shift of 1 hour for daylight savings.  I'm not sure if that applies everywhere daylight savings is used.